# How to set the liferay asset publisher to filter on all tags provided by the url

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

We have one asset publisher on the page. The pageurl is oursite.org/web/dummyorg/structure/tags/country/be .

This provides 2 tags (be and country) towards the asset publisher on that page. The default behavior of the asset publisher is to search for content/documents with one of the given tags.

However we would like to  limit the display to elements with BOTH tags. Is there an extra parameter you can add to the url to achieve this filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it buy, you might want to trying the following:

1. Go to your Asset Publishers Configuration page
2. Under the "Filter" section set it to "Contains", "All", "Tags"
3. Leave "Include tags specified in the URL?" ticked

It should then apply these rules to all tags, not just manually entered ones in the Configuration.

Let us know if it works.

Comment: Hmmmm thought it might be a long shot. You'd expect it to be an extra parameter on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Put your 2 tags in Contains Any Tags then click on + sign. Put all other tags in Does not contain Any tags. You will get your result.
Alternatively, you can also use category for those web content instead of using two tags.